Who was the first to give a proof of the cubic character of 2?
I am writing a paper on the cubic character of 2, and I am interested in the history of how the character of 2 developed. I am aware that Euler was the first to conjecture the form $p=C^{2}+27D^{2}$ for $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, but I am not too aware of who proved it first and what techniques were first used in its proof.
Thank you!

You should consult Lemmermeyer, Reciprocity Laws
From Euler to Eisenstein, there is a brief summary in Wikipedia.
